# How to mask a view with a (different) size constrained view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to mask a `RoundedRectangle` (filled with a gradient) with some view to receive the following result:

[image: Result I want]

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: self.gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .top)
            .mask(
                //WHAT TO PLACE HERE?
             )
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: self.gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 8)
    }
```

However when putting `Rectangle().frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.4, alignment: .leading)` inside the `.mask`, it ignores the given frame width and simply displays the full `RoundedRectangle`:

[image: Rectangle mask]

I've tried other views inside the `.mask` to check if the clipping works at all.

I tried `Circle().frame(alignment: .leading)`, which resulted in:
[image: Circle mask]

*Notice how this doesn't adhere to the given alignment.*

Then I tried `Text("MASKING MASKING").frame(alignment: .trailing)`, which resulted in:
[image]

*Notice how this does adhere to the given alignment.*

I'm very confused as to how I can go about achieving the desired result since SwiftUI masking behaviour seems very unintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is demo of solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
.mask(
    VStack {
        Rectangle().frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.4)
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! Could you explain what internal behaviour of `mask` makes this solution work?

Comment: @M.Koot, VStack consumes all space of parent view (ie. RoundedRectangle with gradient) and it is transparent, but aligns to leading internal content (ie opaque Rectangle with 40% width), so makes mask applied by opaque part of resulting view.